# Instances & classes: requiring x arguments when x-1 given

Tags: python, python-3.x, instantiation, self, pycrypto

I have written the following classes to be able to test different encryption schemes. However, I'm having trouble instantiating objects from the different encryption scheme. Could someone point out to something that doesn't make sense that I'm not catching atm? I'm not sure why it doesn't work. It gives a  `TypeError: encrypt() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)` but it does have self passed, so I don't know how to fix it on the basis of the rest of them.

```
class AXU:
    def __init__(self, sec_param):
        self.sec_param = sec_param

    def getHash(self):
        # sample a, b and return hash function
        a = random.randrange(self.sec_param) 
        b = random.randrange(self.sec_param)

        return lambda x : a*x+b % sec_param

class BC(object):
    def __init__(self, sec_param):
        # generate a key 
        self.sec_param = sec_param

    def encrypt(self, message, key):
        #encrypt with AES?
        cipher = AES.new(key, MODE_CFB, sec_param)
        msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(message)
        return msg

class tBC(object):
    def __init__(self, sec_param):
        self.sec_param = sec_param

    def encrypt(self, tweak, message):
        #pass
        return AES.new(message, tweak)

class Trivial(tBC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bcs = {}

    def encrypt(self, tweak, message):
        if tweak not in self.bcs.keys():
            bc = BC()
            self.bcs[tweak] = bc
        return self.bcs[tweak].encrypt(message)

class Our(tBC):
    def __init__(self, sec_param):
        self.bc1 = BC(sec_param)
        self.bc2 = BC(sec_param)
        self.bc3 = BC(sec_param)
        self.bc4 = BC(sec_param)
        # encryption over GF field
    def encrypt(self, tweak, message):
        return self.bc1.encrypt(self.bc2.encrypt(tweak) * self.bc3.encrypt(message) + self.bc4.encrypt(tweak))
```

Comment: Where exactly do you think you're passing two arguments (aside from `self`)? All `encrypt` calls have a single argument.

Comment: Please do include the *full* traceback. I can guess as to where exactly the error occurs, but a full traceback would tell us for certain and make sure I didn't miss another case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in **one** argument to a bound method:

```
return self.bc1.encrypt(
    self.bc2.encrypt(tweak) * self.bc3.encrypt(message) + 
    self.bc4.encrypt(tweak))
```

That's one argument to the `BC.encrypt()` method each, and this method takes 2 beyond `self`, `message` and `key`.

Either pass in a value for `key`, or remove that argument from the `BC.encrypt()` method definition (and get the key from some place else; perhaps from an instance attribute set in `__init__`).